# How do you write tr:nth-child(odd) in Sass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, sass

Is this sass code valid?

```
tr:nth-child(odd)
  :background-color #cccccc
```

Somehow, it does not color my table's alternating rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What browser are you using?  `nth-child` [isn't presently supported](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) in Firefox, or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#pseudoclasses).  You'll probably have to use the old odd/even classes thing.

Comment: Then you're out of luck.  Sass isn't the problem, the browser is.

Answer (score 1):

Compass provides mixins for styling your tables with sass, it requires some extra css classes due to poor support of CSS3.

See the **Table Utilities** section of [wiki docs](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/compass-core-utilities-module) for more information. A [demo is here](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/utilities.html).